# string replace array map

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a hundreds of user in the list, below is just an example list :

```js
var userList = [
  {
    "FullName": "test1",
    "UserName": "test1",
    "Email": "test1@test.com"
  },
  {
    "FullName": "test2",
    "UserName": "test2",
    "Email": "test2@test.com"
  }
];
 
var userStr = "test1 is doing a  test2";
userList.map((user) => {
 userStr.replace(RegExp(user.FullName,"gi"), user.Email)
})

console.log(userStr);
```

The test string return is still the same and is not replace with email. Is the code I do optimize?

Comment: `map` doesn't modify source array, it returns a new array instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the variable with the returned value.

```js
var userList = [{
  "FullName": "test1",
  "UserName": "test1",
  "Email": "test1@test.com"
}, {
  "FullName": "test2",
  "UserName": "test2",
  "Email": "test2@test.com"
}];

var userStr = "test1 is doing a  test2";
userList.forEach((user) => userStr = userStr.replace(RegExp(user.FullName, "gi"), user.Email))

console.log(userStr);
```